# asp.net mvc session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

are sessions per user?
eg.
Session["Name"] means different things to different users.

do i understand it correctly?

Comment: What are you asking? "Are sessions per-session?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each session has variables associated on a per-session basis.